# How to remove rows in a dataframe that contain certain words in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, words

I'm trying to remove rows in my dataframe that contain a certain word or certain sequences of words. for example:

```
mydf <- as.data.frame(read.xlsx("C:\\data.xlsx, 1, header=T"))
head(df)
#     NO    ARTICLE    
# 1   34    New York Times reports blabla
# 2   42    Financial Times reports blabla
# 3   21    Greenwire reports blabla
# 4    3    New York Times reports blabla
# 5   46    Newswire reports blabla
```

I want to remove the rows that contain the string "New York Times" and "Newswire" from my `data.frame`. I have tried different approaches using `%in%` or `grep`, but I'm not quite sure how to use this!

How do I do that?

Comment: `df[!grepl('New York Times',df$Article),]`, etc.

Comment: @Thomas - Why don't you post as an answer?

Answer (score 9):

Per my comment, use `grepl`, which returns a logical value when a specified string is found in your vector. In your case, something like:

```
df[!grepl('New York Times',df$Article),]
```

should do the trick.

Comment: How can this be generalised to remove rows in which any vector contains the string of interest? i.e. something like `df[!grepl('New York Times', df),]`

Comment: @DavidPell Depends a bit on whether your variables are all character. I would suggest posting a new question, as the answer will be too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: Done - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645801/remove-rows-containing-string-in-any-vector-in-data-frame

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, since the OP wanted to remove multiple matches.

Answer (score 7):

```
# Sample Data
NO <- c(34, 42, 21, 3)
ARTICLE <- c('New York Times reports blah blah fake news',
             'Financial Times blah blah',
             'Fox News has been very nice to me',
             'Newswire reports blah blah')
df <- data.frame(NO, ARTICLE)

# Create List of Exclusion Phrases
fakenews <- c('New York Times', 'Newswire')

# Exclude
very.nice.to.me <- df[ !grepl(paste(fakenews, collapse="|"), df$ARTICLE),]
```

Comment: This works perfectly. And it is lightning fast, even though I have over 250.000 rows and nearly 200 different words that I want to exclude.

Comment: What does the collapse argument do?

Comment: The `collapse` function takes a vector input and outputs a single string, in this case separated by |.