# Remove rows containing string in any vector in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing a number of vectors that contain strings I would like to remove rows that contain a certain string.

```
df <- data.frame(id=seq(1:10),
             foo=runif(10),
             sapply(letters[1:5],function(x) {sample(letters,10,T)} ),
             bar=runif(10))
```

This can be done on a single vector by specifying the vector name i.e.

```
df <- df[!grepl("b", df$a),]
```

which I can then repeat specifying each vector e.g.

```
df <- df[!grepl("b", df$b),]
df <- df[!grepl("b", df$c),]
df <- df[!grepl("b", df$d),]
df <- df[!grepl("b", df$e),]
```

but is it possible to do it in one line without having to specify which columns contain the string? Something like:

```
df <- df[!grepl("b", df),]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
df[-which(df=="b", arr.ind=TRUE)[,1],]
```

or, as suggested by @docendodiscimus

```
df[rowSums(df == "b") == 0,]
```

This second option is preferable because it does not lead to any difficulty if no matching pattern is found.

Comment: I have found negating indexes a slightly dangerous approach, since it will returns an empty data.frame when there are not matches. For example `df[-which(df=="ab", arr.ind=TRUE)[,1],]`. That is also why I would mostly prefer `grepl` over `grep`

Comment: I agree. Your suggestion is better.

Comment: Please feel free to add it to your answer

Comment: Thank you, @docendodiscimus

Answer (score 4):

Paste columns then grepl:

```
df[!grepl("b", paste0(df$a, df$b, df$c, df$d, df$e)), ]
```

Identify factor (or character columns) then paste:

```
df[!grepl("b", 
          apply(df[, sapply(df, class) == "factor"], 1, paste0, collapse = ",")), ]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - but ideally I wouldn't have to specify the columns anywhere as in practice I may have very many

Answer (score 1):

```
target_cols <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
df[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[,target_cols], function(col) grepl("b", col))),]
```

Comment: thanks - but again as in my comment above - ideally I wouldn't have to specify which columns contain the string as in practice there could be lots

Comment: I wanted to show more flexible solution, but without specifying columns it would be even simpler `df[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, function(col) grepl("b", col))),]` there must be backticks around `|` like in answer, but in comments they disappear